# magento product create (multiple SOAP connections) fails with SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: magento, soap

My problem:

100 products are split into 4 x 25 chunks, for performance reason.
There are 4 SOAP connections each trying to process own chunk from above (25 products), at the same time, with SOAP message to magento (1.9.3) API:

```
catalogProductCreate
```

Unfortunately Magento randomly throws an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`magentodb`.`catalog_product_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT
 `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELE)'
```

However when doing the same just with one chunk 100 products (exactly the same products as with 4 chunks) everything works fine.

Does it mean that Magento can not work in parallel when adding new products?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out, or how to work around it?

Comment: I'm also interested in a work around if you've found it? The more connections, the more frequent the error.